# Add event in calendar not working

Tags: android, calendar

I have tried to add event in calendar using below code. Its working fine with all devices except Nexus 6 (OS 6.0.1). Its showing Log like `added event: content://com.android.calendar/events/1598` in Logcat. But that event is not showing up in my calendar.

Code:

```
private void addEvents() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("calendar_id", 1);
        values.put("title", "event Name");
        values.put("allDay", 0);
        values.put("dtstart", myCalendar.getTimeInMillis() + 11*60*1000); // event starts at 11 minutes from now
        values.put("dtend", myCalendar.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000); // ends 60 minutes from now
        values.put("description", "event desc");
        values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE,TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        ContentResolver resolver=getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();

        Uri event = resolver.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

        Log.d("added event",event.toString());
    }
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: same here, don't see  the event on android 7.0

Comment: any solution ? same issue